# What service to restart after modifying /etc/sudoers for macOS to make changes active without reboot?

Tags: services, sudo, launch-services

What's the service that needs to be restarted after modifying `/etc/sudoers` for macOS in order to make changes active without a system reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None.  No system process reads /etc/sudoers.  The command line binary sudo(1) reads /etc/sudoers.

Changes are immediate when they are saved.

Comment: Good to know and confirmatory of apparently a mistake I made in the definition (eg, why it didn't work as expected).